# How does CMake find the vtk library dirs when using PCL

Tags: c++, cmake, vtk, point-cloud-library

I am using a project structure for cmake that is a little unusual. My project is divided into modules. Each module yields an object-library and a bunch of variables that contain metainformation necessary to put the modules together. The one i am having a problem with is the one containing the library dirs for `link_directories`.

In an old project there is the following section

```
find_package (PCL 1.7 REQUIRED COMPONENTS common io)
include_directories (${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions (${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
```

Subsequent linking of ${PCL_LIBRARIES} just works. The linker script correctly contains references to `/usr/lib64/vtk/vtkSomeLibrary.so.1`.

However when i eliminate side-effects by calling `find_package` from another subdir and only use the given variables the vtk libraries that pcl needs are not found at all. When i examined `PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS` i noticed, that it just contains `/usr/lib64`.

So i thought that maybe the VTKConfig.cmake actually calls `link_directories` so i examined the `LINK_DIRECTORIES` property of my dir. It just contains `/usr/lib64`.

It got really strange when i grepped through the VTKConfig.cmake scripts and realized that `VTK_LIBRARY_DIRS` is never actually set. In the old project the first occasion where i encountered the correct path (`/usr/lib64/vtk`) was in the linker script.

Where does this path come from? At this point i am more interested in why the old project does work, than why the new one doesn't.

Edit: I am trying to use pcl. It requires. vtk though. The pcl package should also contain vtk information

Comment: Your code uses `find_package(PCL)` but you talk about `VTKConfig.cmake`, which corresponds to `VTK` package. Also, `PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS` can rarely be set to `/usr/lib64`. Do you mean `PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS`? Please, recheck names of files and variables in your question post.

Comment: Seems to be a bug in Fedora22. Can't narrow it down though. Under Ubuntu 14.04 it works flawlessly.

Comment: `The pcl package should also contain vtk information` - If PCL uses VTK *internally* it needn't to export VTK information outside. And this [findPCL.cmake](https://github.com/ethz-asl/libpointmesher/blob/master/cmake/FindPCL.cmake) actually *doesn't add* VTK-related libraries to `PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS`. If you need VTK libraries, use `find_package(VTK)`. BTW, this [VTKConfig.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/VTK/blob/master/CMake/VTKConfig.cmake.in) actually set `VTK_LIBRARY_DIRS` via `vtk_module_config()` call.

Comment: Arbitrary compilations against vtk fail and pcl actually includes vtk libraries. It fails to set the library dir properly.